# PyTorch FasterRCNN TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, faster-rcnn, torchvision

I am working on object detection and I have a dataset containing images and their corresponding bounding boxes (ground-truth values).

I actually have built my own feature extractor which takes an image as input and outputs a feature map(basically an encoder-decoder system where the final output of the decoder is the same as the image size and has 3 channels). Now, I want to feed this feature map as an input to a FasterRCNN model for detection instead of the original image. I am using the following code to add the feature map(using RTFNet to generate feature map -  code at this [link](https://github.com/yuxiangsun/RTFNet/blob/master/model/RTFNet.py)) on top the FRCNN detection module

```
frcnn_model = fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)
in_features = frcnn_model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
frcnn_model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)
fpn_block = frcnn_model.backbone.fpn
rpn_block = frcnn_model.rpn

backbone = RTFNet(num_classes) RTFNet is a feature extractor taking as input, an image having 4 channels(fused RGB and thermal image) , 
model = nn.Sequential(backbone, nn.ReLU(inplace=True))
model = nn.Sequential(model,fpn_block)
model = nn.Sequential(model,rpn_block)
model = nn.Sequential(model,FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes))
```

I am just trying to test and see if it is working by using the following code which generates random images and bounding boxes

```
images, boxes = torch.rand(1, 4, 512, 640), torch.rand(4, 11, 4)
labels = torch.randint(1, num_classes, (4, 11))
images = list(image for image in images)
targets = []
for i in range(len(images)):
  d = {}
  d['boxes'] = boxes[i]
  d['labels'] = labels[i]
  targets.append(d)
output = model(images, targets)
```

Running this gives me the following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-2637b8c27ad2> in <module>()
----> 1 output = model(images, targets)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    530             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    531         else:
--> 532             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    533         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    534             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

However, when I replace my model with a normal FasterRCNN Model with the following,

```
model = fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)
in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)
```

there is no error and it works fine

Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This is because only the image inputs should be passed into the models, instead of both images and the ground truth targets. So instead of doing `output = model(images, targets)`, you can do `output = model(images)`.

As for why the error message talks about being given 3 positional arguments, this is because forward is initiated with a default `self` keyword, which represents the class instance. So in addition to `self`, you should only give 1 more argument, which would be the input image.

Comment: Okay, but how and where should I pass the targets ?

Comment: Think about it, the model predictions never depend on the ground truth annotations. Hence the targets are only passed when evaluating the accuracy of predictions, and are passed into your loss function.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely makes sense. Thanks for the clarification. However, when I pass only the image and not the training labels, I get the a Value Error saying that targets must be passed while training.

ValueError: In training mode, targets should be passed
The entire traceback is at this [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12kR07689EAQLdtDjSeWpKOqlFjEZEZ82#scrollTo=QdxP-h-8DThp&line=1&uniqifier=1).    

Any workaround for this?

Comment: It seems like I don't have access to the link?

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12kR07689EAQLdtDjSeWpKOqlFjEZEZ82

Comment: Sorry about that, I have sent the updated link in the above comment. The error is in the 2nd last cell

Comment: I think it's because you are using 2 models: RTFNet and the pretrained  faster-rcnn model. The former takes 2 input arguments, while the latter takes 3.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was the issue after you posted the answer. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: You could allow passing of the target argument into RTFNet, but not perform operations on it, for an easy fix.

Comment: I tried what you said but am getting another error (saying list object is not callable) while passing the targets as well. Here is the [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12kR07689EAQLdtDjSeWpKOqlFjEZEZ82#scrollTo=-g9kJPAeJxVS)

Comment: You have to change some of the corresponding code in RTFNet as well... It's very trivial, you just need to re-define images from a list to 1 variable, using something like `self.images, self.targets = input`. This is just generic code, you'll have to tweak it to suit your program